# Angular JS. Show country flags in UI while I have only ID of country

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my JSON structure has `countryIds` field:

```
[
    {countryIds: [1, 35, 16]}
    {countryIds: [6, 21]}
]
```

And in UI I want to show country flag instead of country ID.

So, for this purpose I think I can create service which will return url for icon flag:

```
getCountryFlagIconUrlById(countryId) {
  switch(countryId) {
    case 1: return "http://mySite:8080/resources/usa.png"
    .....
    case 200: return "http://mySite:8080/resources/russia.png"
  }
```

But the problem is that I need to create `switch-case` operator for more than 200 countries.

Is there any more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use a map

```
var countries = { 
   1: 'usa',
   ...,
   200: 'russia'
};
```

with getCountryFlagIconUrlById as the following:

```
function getCountryFlagIconUrlById(id) {
  return 'http://localhost:8080/resources/'+countries[id]+'.png';

}
```

current downside is that it does not check if the id exists, but that is a simple if statement.

Answer (score 3):

For a more angular approach store your countries as a JSON map in a `.factory` with name value pairs for the ID and png.

Then create a custom `.filter` that maps the value based on the id used as input.  [Filter Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/eLtzdv3e/)**

```
app.factory('FlagFactory', function() {
     return {
        1: "usa",
        2: "russia",
        ...
        ...
     };
});

app.filter('flag', ['FlagFactory', function(FlagFactory) {
  return function(input) {
     return "http://mySite:8080/resources/" + FlagFactory[input] + ".png";
  };
});
```

*This would then be easy to implement and reusable across your whole app.*

```
<html> Hello World {{someCountryID | flag}}  </html>
```

**Additional Note**:

If you are going to use plan on using the angular model to update the src for an image tag you should use `ng-src` otherwise the website will try to fetch the image with the literal hash {{someimage}} before angular replaces it.

```
<img ng-src="{{foo | flag}}" alt="flag" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're countryIds are unique [which they should be, You can rename your images accordingly and redesign your code as

```
getCountryFlagIconUrlById(countryId) {
    return "http://mySite:8080/resources/" + countryId + ".png"
}
```

Another approach will be, if your json structure allows, to user country ids to get country names and fetch the images accordingly..

That is, if you have

> {1 : "country1", 2: "country2"}

You can modify the method like this

```
getCountryFlagIconUrlById(countryId) {
    return "http://mySite:8080/resources/" + countryJSON[countryId] + ".png"
}
```